# Parse Server - Installation class missing user column

Tags: push-notification, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I am trying to send push notification to specific user using parse server. However, the Installation Class doesn't have the user column that points to which user has this installation. Hence, the query for the installation returns nothing. My question is should the installation class create the user column automatically, or should I relate them somehow? and if so, any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm sending the push notification using Cloud Code. So I'm using javascript.

Comment: you have to link User class (pointer) with Installation class manually... the ideal way is when you create new Installation at client save the User id to the Installation class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Installation class does not automatically set the User column - you have to do it manually.

I suggest that you create and save the User, and then the success callback will have the saved User object as a parameter, and you can then set the User in your Installation document.

Here's a quick snippet:

```
var currentInstallation;
installationModule.getInstallationById(installationId)
  .then(function (installation) {
    if (installation) {
      currentInstallation = installation;
      var user = createParseUser(newUser);
      return user.save();
    }
    else {
      // return error
    }
  })
  .then(function (user) {
    currentInstallation.set('user', user);
    return currentInstallation.save()
  }, function (error) {
    // TODO: handle error
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do that an afterSave cloud function for Parse.User? or is it better to do an afterSave for Parse.Session, because different users might sign in from the same device. your thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful. Regarding the triggers, for starters, Parse.Session does not have Cloud Code triggers, unlike other Classes. This means that you cannot use afterSave on Parse.Session. As for using afterSave on Parse.User, it's a good idea in theory but my only concern is that you will not have the Installation object in the trigger in order to associate the User to it.

Comment: Yep I after I've tried the Parse.Session trigger it did not work. I've decided to do it on the client side, I think it's the simplest way.